# Is the image of a matrix Lie group under a Lie homomorphism again a Lie group?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification, lie-groups, examples-counterexamples

> Suppose $G\in GL_{n_1}(\mathbb C),H\in GL_{n_2}(\mathbb C)$ are matrix Lie groups such that $\theta:G\to H$ is a Lie homomorphism . Then is the image of G under the map necessarily a matrix Lie group?

I thought the answer would be positive.

> Definition of matrix Lie group:  a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ such that any sequence converges to an element in A or to an element which is not invertible; i.e., closed under $GL_n(\mathbb C)$

I attempted like the following:

$A_n\in G$ such that $A_n \to A$ as $n\to \infty$

As $\theta $ is a continuous map it must converge and limit is in range .

So its image must be a closed subgroup of $H$.

Hence a matrix Lie group.

Is this correct? Or there exists some counterexample to claim?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No, the homomorphic image need not be a closed subgroup, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895514/if-the-image-of-a-lie-group-homomorphism-is-included-in-a-subgroup-is-it-a-subg).

Comment: Dear Sir, I read that answer . as I am doing matrix lie group course with topology in same semester. I am not able to get that answer. As  it contains covering map. Can you please suggest me some reading or explain that answer?

Comment: Do you know about dense windings on tori?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Sir I do not know that.

Comment: Think about $T^2$ as the quotient space $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.  Pick your favorite irrational number $r$ and consider the curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\gamma(t) = (t, rt)$.  It's projection to $T^2$ gives a curve.  Since $\gamma$ is clearly a homomorphism, it's projection to $T^2$ is also a homomorphism.  The curve in $T^2$ never closes up (because $r$ is irrational) and has dense image, essentially because irrational numbers can be well approximated by rational numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be the group of reals under addition, identified with the matrix Lie group of 1x1 matrices with positive determinant via the exponential map $x\mapsto e^x$; let $a$ be an irrational number and consider $f:G\rightarrow GL(2,\mathbb C)$ given by

$$
f(x)= diag(e^{2i\pi x},e^{2i\pi ax}) .
$$

You can prove that the image of $f$ is not closed in $GL(2,\mathbb C)$.

**Remark.** This is basically the same example provided by @Jason DeVito but rewritten it to make matrices appear explicitly.